# Is '@model dynamic' valid in an ASP.NET MVC3 .cshtml page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, razor

I am writing a little ASP.NET MVC3 app that I am running on Mac OS X. It is working great but I have an unresolved question. I am using the Razor syntax. For example, this is a simplified version of the login page:

```
@model Livestream.LoginModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Remote Observation</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/Content/CSS/main.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
    @{
        dynamic dave = "Sign In";
    }
    <div class='normal center'>
        <p><img src='/Content/images/logo.png' /></p>
        @using(Html.BeginForm("Login", "Main")) {
            <div class='loginBox'>
                 <p>Username<br />@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)</p>
                 <p>Password<br />@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)</p>
                 <p><input type='submit' value='@dave'></p>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('Username').focus();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok, so no problems with that. It works great on both Mac OS X and Linux.

After reading the comments in [this post by Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx), I thought I understood that I could replace `@model Livestream.LoginModel` with `@model dynamic`. When I tried it though, it would not work on either OS X or Linux.

Given that I am developing in ASP.NET, it may seem crazy but I do not have access to a Windows machine with .NET to try this there. I am using [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page) obviously.

Should I be able to use `@model dynamic` or did I misunderstand Scott in that post? Is there something else I need to do to make it work? Or is this a bug in Mono?

My app is using the .NET 4 profile (CLR 4.0) so it is not that it does not support dynamic. I can use dynamic elsewhere in the code.

The actual error I get is that it could not find the 'cshtml' file. I believe that is what happens when the view fails to compile.

**EDIT**: I added "dynamic dave" above to verify that my views are indeed using .NET 4 language features. So, I can use `dynamic` but not in `@model`. Should I be able to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@model dynamic` should work perfectly fine.  In fact, the Razor view engine defaults to @model dynamic, so you don't even need to declare it, but doing so is fine as well.  It looks like the problem you're getting has to do with MVC not being able to find the view.  Can you show us the whole error message?

I created a sample .cshtml file with simply this in it and it worked fine:

```
@model dynamic

@Model.Name
```

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that you're using a lambda expression to generate your textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
```

You can't do this because you can't pass in a dynamic as an expression.  You'll need to do this instead:

```
@Html.TextBox("Username")
```

Comment: Thanks JohnnyO. Your update was it exactly. If I change the lambdas to magic text then it works fine. Nice catch. As I said in the question, the error was that it could not find the view. The real problem was that the view was not compiling though. Perhaps .NET offers a more useful error message in this case.